# ng-file-upload not working for IE9

Tags: c#, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I'm trying to use the following angular directive to support file upload in IE9 but I'm having issues making the request from the front end to the API I have. The following works for all IE versions after 9.

This is the angular service request I am making:

```
    uploadFiles: function (data) {

        angular.forEach(data.files, function (file) {

                file.upload = Upload.upload({
                    url: fullUploadUrl,
                    data: { file: file }
                });

                file.upload.then(function (response) {
                    if (response.data.length > 0) {
                        console.log("Success")
                    } else {
                        console.log("Successish")
                    }
                }, function (response) {
                    console.log("fail")
                });
        });
    },
```

And the .net restful API I'm trying to hit:

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(List<FileUploadBindingModel>))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
    {
        HttpPostedFile file = null;

        foreach (string fileKey in HttpContext.Current.Request.Files)
        {
             file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[fileKey];
             //Do things with files
        }
    }
```

I've also added the following policy file (crossdomain.xml) to the route directory of the API and the front end:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Can anyone point out what I am missing here? The request makes it as far as the file.upload but then nothing happens.

A little bit more on some semi relevant info:

This is how am bundling together all the files I use:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/js").Include(
            "~/Assets/libs/jquery-{version}.js",
            "~/Assets/libs/bootstrap.js",
            "~/Assets/libs/google-analytics.js",
            "~/Assets/libs/scrolling-nav.js",
            "~/Assets/libs/AngularJS/angular.min.js",
            "~/Assets/libs/AngularJS/angular-sanitize.js",
            "~/Assets/libs/AngularJS/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js",
            "~/Assets/libs/AngularJS/angular-route/angular-route.min.js",
            "~/Assets/libs/AngularJS/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js",
            "~/Assets/libs/AngularJS/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload-shim.js",
            "~/Assets/libs/AngularJS/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.js",
            "~/Assets/libs/AngularJS/angular-form-extension/*.js",
            "~/Assets/libs/AngularJS/angular-local-storage.min.js",
            "~/Assets/libs/AngularJS/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js",
            "~/Assets/libs/AngularJS/angular-translate/angular-translate.js",
            "~/Assets/libs/AngularJS/angular-translate/angular-translate-cookie-storage.js",
            "~/Assets/libs/AngularJS/angular-translate/angular-translate-local-storage.js",
            "~/Assets/libs/AngularJS/angular-translate/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js",
            "~/Assets/libs/AngularJS/angular-smooth-scroll.js"));
```

The requests made between the front end and the .net api is using token authentication, so each request must contain this token. The above request does contain this.

The folder containing all relevent files:

[image]

The file just before the request is sent:

[image]

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @danial None, there is no error. It just does nothing after making the request. I've tried wrapping it in in a try catch in case the error was getting suppressed somehow but there is still nothing.

Comment: Put some breakpoints on `FileAPI.upload` line and `onComplete` to make sure it does send it to the server. complete call back is were the server response comes back.

Comment: @danial I've put a breakpoint on xhr.__fileApiXHR = FileAPI.upload(config); and I can see the request come in on config but I can't see anything happen after that. I can't find onComplete, is it part of the flash file?

Comment: It is `complete: function (err, fileApiXHR) {...`

Comment: Does the config have the file with flashId? You can also monitor your server for any request that is coming.

Comment: @danial I've included an image of what config is at the request, The flashId is there. I've been monitoring the outgoing requests and responses using fiddler but I don't see any requests of responses. I've tried putting a breakpoint and some logging around the complete but it doesn't seem to reach that point, I've tried letting it just timeout to see if I was not giving it enough time but nothing is happening after about 5 mins.

Comment: The request is being send using Flash so you won't be able to see it in the browser's network tab. You need to monitor your network with a tool like wireshark or something. Since the upload seems to be called correctly I believe the server is not responding. Try to put breakpoint in your server code where the request is being sent. You can try changing the upload url to the one from the demo page to make sure it is the server issue.

Comment: Did you tried this - https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload#-old-browsers

Answer (score 0):

IE 9 and below does not support asynchronous file uploads. This means that Angular can't upload files on those browsers using its client side goodness. I think its a limitation on the XmlHttpRequest object if I am not mistaken.

You need to have a back-up strategy for older browsers.

Here are two options that have explicit support for older browsers:

https://github.com/leon/angular-upload - uses iframes as a fallback

https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload - uses FileAPI/Flash as a fallback